# Passing data from an iframe

Tags: iframe

I'm trying to build a form that will be embedded in customer websites via an iframe, and I'm struggling to figure out how to pass data from my iframe back to the customer website it's embedded on.

I basically want to do what [Plaid Link](https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#client-side-link-configuration) does with their iframe, where when they finish authentication, they call the parent website's `onSuccess` function, feeding in a `public_token` and some metadata as parameters. How do I get that token and metadata from my server to the client iframe and then to the website the iframe is embedded on?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) - it lets you communicate between a iframe and its host window.